# Azure Key Vault Domain Names for National Clouds

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

What are the domain names for Azure Key Vault for National Clouds?

Answer (score 2):

They can be found on this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.profile/get-azurermenvironment?view=azurermps-6.7.0&viewFallbackFrom=azurermps-6.5.0):

- For China cloud: https://vault.azure.cn
- For US Gov cloud: https://vault.usgovcloudapi.net
- For Germany: https://vault.microsoftazure.de